# Restrict the background colour in a ParametricPlot region

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, color, regions, background

I am trying to plot this diagram, distinguished into three separate regions by the white curve. The code that I used for this purpose is provided below:

```
r[x_] = (-1 + 5 x^4)/(4 x^5); s[x_] = (-1 + 3 x^4)/(2 x^6);
bg = Polygon[{ImageScaled[{0, 0}], ImageScaled[{0.5, 0}], 
    ImageScaled[{1, 0}], ImageScaled[{1, 1}], ImageScaled[{0.78, 1}], 
    ImageScaled[{0, 1}]}, 
   VertexColors -> {Green, Red, Blue, Blue, Red, Green}];
p0 = ParametricPlot[{r[x], s[x]}, {x, -100, 100}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0.0, 1.5}, {0.0, 1.5}}, AspectRatio -> 0.5, 
  PlotTheme -> "Scientific", PlotStyle -> {White, Thick},
  Epilog -> {{{Blue, Disk[{1, 1}, {0.03, 0.035}, {0, 2 Pi/3}]}, {Red, 
      Disk[{1, 1}, {0.03, 0.035}, {2 Pi/3, 4 Pi/3}]}, {Green, 
      Disk[{1, 1}, {0.03, 0.035}, {4 Pi/3, 2 \[Pi]}]}}, {PointSize[
      0.03], Darker[Blue], Point[{0.1, 1}], Darker[Red], 
     Point[{0.7, 0.3}], Darker[Green], Point[{1.4, 1}]}},
  Prolog -> {Rotate[bg, 180*Degree], {GrayLevel[0.9], Dotted, 
     Line[{{0, 1}, {1, 1}}], InfiniteLine[{{1, 0}, {1, 1}}], 
     InfiniteLine[{{0.66, 0}, {0.66, 1}}]}}]
```

which gives me the following result:

[image: phase diagram]

As you can see from the figure, the red-coloured region spreads away because of my choice of Polygon. I wish to restrict the red-coloured region in between the white curve. What modification should I make in my original code to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given functions are

```
r[x_] = (-1 + 5 x^4)/(4 x^5); s[x_] = (-1 + 3 x^4)/(2 x^6);
```

Backgrounds

```
bg1 = Polygon[{{0.1, 0}, {0, 0}, {1.5, 0}, {1.5, 1.5}, {1.1, 1.5}, {0,
      1.5}}, VertexColors -> {Lighter[Green, 0.00], Green, Blue, Blue,
      Red, Green}];
bg2 = Polygon[{{0, 0}, {0, 1.5}, {1.5, 1.5}, {1.5, 0}}, 
   VertexColors -> {Green, Blue, Blue, Lighter[Green, 0.2]}];
```

The required plot

```
ParametricPlot[{r[x], s[x]}, {x, -100, 100}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0.0, 1.5}, {0.0, 1.5}}, AspectRatio -> 0.5, 
  PlotTheme -> "Scientific", ImageSize -> 1800, 
  LabelStyle -> {44, Black}, PlotStyle -> {White, Thick},
 
  Prolog -> {Rotate[bg2, 90*Degree], Rotate[bg1, 180*Degree],
{GrayLevel[0.9], Dotted, Line[{{0, 1}, {1, 1}}], 
     InfiniteLine[{{1, 0}, {1, 1}}], 
     InfiniteLine[{{0.66, 0}, {0.66, 1}}]}}]
```

[image]

> I could not find another way to do it. Therefore, I used two background polygons, one over another. I hope this suffices your needs.

Answer (score 2):

You can (1) replace `Red` with `Blue` in definition of `bg` and (2) post-process `ParametricPlot` output to add a `FilledCurve` with desired style:

```
r[x_] = (-1 + 5 x^4)/(4 x^5); s[x_] = (-1 + 3 x^4)/(2 x^6);

bg = Polygon[{ImageScaled[{0, 0}], ImageScaled[{0.5, 0}], 
    ImageScaled[{1, 0}], ImageScaled[{1, 1}], ImageScaled[{0.78, 1}], 
    ImageScaled[{0, 1}]}, 
   VertexColors -> {Green, Blue, Blue, Blue, Blue, Green}];

epilog = {{{Blue, Disk[{1, 1}, {0.03, 0.035}, {0, 2 Pi/3}]}, 
  {Red, Disk[{1, 1}, {0.03, 0.035}, {2 Pi/3, 4 Pi/3}]},
  {Green, Disk[{1, 1}, {0.03, 0.035}, {4 Pi/3, 2 \[Pi]}]}}, 
  {PointSize[0.03], Darker[Blue], Point[{0.1, 1}], Darker[Red], 
   Point[{0.7, 0.3}], Darker[Green], Point[{1.4, 1}]}};

prolog = {Rotate[bg, 180*Degree], {GrayLevel[0.9], Dotted, 
    Line[{{0, 1}, {1, 1}}], InfiniteLine[{{1, 0}, {1, 1}}], 
    InfiniteLine[{{0.66, 0}, {0.66, 1}}]}};

pp = ParametricPlot[{ r[x], s[x]}, {x, -100, 100}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0.0, 1.5}, {0.0, 1.5}}, AspectRatio -> 0.5, 
  PlotTheme -> "Scientific", PlotStyle -> {White, Thick}, 
  DisplayFunction -> 
   ReplaceAll[l_Line :> {Red, Opacity[1], FilledCurve[l], White, l}]]
```

[image]

```
Show[pp, Epilog -> epilog, Prolog -> prolog]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response! Actually I don't wish a solid Filled curve in my plot. I wish to get a gradient like feel just like in the blue and green regions, basically I wish the colours to mix as well. Any other way I can make it happen without using a filled curve? I hope you understand the idea.

Comment: @codebpr, I can't think of a way to mix colors. I will post an update if I find a way.